# boto script to list all api gateway deployments

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, jq, boto

I have several API's deployed using gateway. How do I list all of them along with details like type of integration (like lambda) and method response (like 200) in tabular format?

---

Update:
As suggested in the answer, I can use "get-rest-apis" method to get the list of all API ID's.
The json data can be converted to pandas dataframe like this...

```
# aws apigateway get-rest-apis --region=us-east-1 > /tmp/to_file.json

import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open("to_file.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = json_normalize(data, "items")

df["createdDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["createdDate"], unit="s").dt.date
df = df.sort_values(["createdDate"])

df["endpointConfiguration.types"] = df["endpointConfiguration.types"].str[0]
```

But how do I query to get details of each ID?

---

In order to get the complete picture of a given API, I need to query several methods like get-integration, get-method-response, get-resource. Each one of these has different number of required parameters that makes the automation process very difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it might not satisfy all of your requirements (or it might be just what you need), easiest and most standardized way of achieving what you want is to export your REST API to an OpenAPI format (former ["Swagger"](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/about/) format). Support for version 3.0 was [recently added](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/amazon-api-gateway-adds-support-for-openapi-3-api-specification/) to API Gateway. You may augment/extend the output JSON with additional information that you need.

Official documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-export-api.html

Comment: This combined with the get-deployments call should get you integration info

Comment: ApiId is required in almost all API calls. How do I get the list of all ApiIds?

Comment: Do you have CLI set up? aws apigateway get-rest-apis

Comment: This will return the first ID, but how do I supply it to other API's to get more info? aws apigateway get-rest-apis | jq '.items[0].id'

Comment: I expected that someone must have written some script to automate all this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Boto is the Amazon Web Services (AWS) SDK for Python. Showing the output in the tabular format can be achieved by using Python output techniques along with different Python data structures.

In the following links, you can find API references that you can use for your API Gateway deployments to get all the information that you require using APIs like `get_deployments()`, `get_integration()`, `get_integration_response()`, etc:

1. [Boto3 API Gateway APIs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html)
2. [Boto3 API Gateway v2 APIs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigatewayv2.html)

If you want to use AWS CLI, you can use `--output table` parameter with the respective CLI command. For example: `aws apigateway get-deployments --rest-api-id 1234123412 --output table`

You can find the reference for AWS CLI commands for AWS API Gateway service here: [AWS API Gateway CLI Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used to get all my API Gateway deployments:

```py
import boto3
gateway = boto3.client('apigateway')
all_rest_apis = gateway.get_rest_apis()
all_rest_apis['items']
```